# Do I/Am I making it the function recursive?

Tags: python, tkinter

I have three functions for a game, as follows:

```
def round():
    global board
    board_copy = [[x for x in row] for row in board]
    for row in range(n):
        for col in range(n):
            if countNeighbors(row,col) == 3:
                board_copy[row][col] = LIVE
                canvas.itemconfigure(rect[row][col],fill='red')
            elif countNeighbors(row,col) > 3 or countNeighbors(row,col) < 2:
                board_copy[row][col] = DEAD
                canvas.itemconfigure(rect[row][col],fill='black')
    board = board_copy

def start():
    round()
    global alarm
    alarm = window.after(500,round)

def stop():
    global alarm
    window.after.cancel(alarm)
```

I want the `start()` function to run `round()` every 500 milliseconds until the user calls on `stop()` (with a button). However, calling `start()` only gives me two iterations of `round()` before coming to a complete stop.

Comment: Try calling the start function from the window.after statement instead of the round function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try this:

```
game_active = True

def round():
    global board, alarm, game_active

    if not game_active:
      return

    board_copy = [[x for x in row] for row in board]
    for row in range(n):
        for col in range(n):
            if countNeighbors(row,col) == 3:
                board_copy[row][col] = LIVE
                canvas.itemconfigure(rect[row][col],fill='red')
            elif countNeighbors(row,col) > 3 or countNeighbors(row,col) < 2:
                board_copy[row][col] = DEAD
                canvas.itemconfigure(rect[row][col],fill='black')
    board = board_copy

    alarm = window.after(500, round)

def start():
    global game_active
    game_active = True
    round()

def stop():
    global alarm, game_active
    window.after.cancel(alarm)
    game_active = False
```

Basically, we make the round function call itself again and again.

Comment: Thanks! Any chance you also know why `stop()` doesn't end the calls?

Comment: Hi, please check the new version, i've edited my code. Hope it is what you need, haven't tested it, i'm writing from my tablet.

Comment: No dice. Not sure what the following error means: "AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'cancel'"

Comment: Removing the line "window.after.cancel(alarm)" should do the trick. Just setting the "game_active" variable to False makes the function "round" not call itself again.